# fastest way to port some Java business logic to iOS (ObjC/C++?)

Tags: java, ios, converters

I have some Java classes, written for Android, implementing quite sophisticated business logic.
They don't use any Android-specific API and only quite basic Java API and language features.
It was already ported in very short time to a webservice.

Now I need to re-implement this for iOS.
I think using some kind of automatic code converter could safe a lot of time here, but I don't have any experience with such a thing yet.

What I found:
http://www.xmlvm.org/overview/
and
http://code.google.com/p/java2objc/

As I understand converting to C++ code should also be an option, is that correct? Would that be easier? Example:
http://tangiblesoftwaresolutions.com/Product_Details/Java_to_CPlusPlus_Converter_Details.html

I'm aware of the fact that the code produced by such tools may not be usable as is.
Does anyone have experience with them and give any advice?

Comment: As you pointed out, the code will most likely be unusable. Since you will have to support this code, you will be far better off learning (insert target language here) rather than doing the conversion.  Especially if you already know (insert source language here)

Comment: I would be more concerned with **accuracy**, **correctness** and **maintainability** than speed of creation.

Answer (score 0):

xmlvm works very well.  We used it on a project to convert Java to Objective C.  They have changed the implementation slightly.  Their user group is very helpful as well.

Comment: That sounds encouraging. Will it be difficult to port just some classes and add them to an existing project?